# Firestore Primera added

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy realizando una escucha en tiempo real a una coleccion de la base de datos de firebase , en la primera escucha me devuelve todos los datos de la coleccion.

```
 db.collection("mensajes")
            .document(id_sala)
            .collection("usuarios")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w("TAG", "listen:error", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                            QueryDocumentSnapshot document = dc.getDocument();
                    //Acciones con el document

                }
            });
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo limitar la primera escucha? Porque si tengo 1000 registros voy a tener los 1000 registros de inicio cuando solo quiero los 10 primero.

He probado con limit pero tambien limita tanto los datos inicial como las siguientes escuchas. Mejor dicho solo me muestran limit datos

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Es evidente que lo correcto sería usar `limit`, si es que tienes bien montada la estructura de datos. Pero esto es totalmente confuso: *He probado con limit pero tambien limita tanto los datos inicial como las siguientes escuchas. Mejor dicho solo me muestran limit datos.*  ¿Qué quieres decir con eso?  ¿De qué modo estás usando `limit`? ¿[Leíste la documentación al respecto](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?hl=es-419) (ten en cuenta que hay ejemplos para varios casos, mira los de Android)?

Comment: Como comenta A.Cedano  ¿De qué modo estás usando `limit`?  me parece que si usas `limit` puedes realizar lo que necesitas.

Comment: no me he explicado bien , el problema es que la primera escucha me da todos los datos y no quiero tener todos los datos. Pero si uso el limit puedo no ver nuevos datos @A.Cedano

Comment: Sigue sin entenderse. Muestra de que forma usas `limiit` , muestra que resultados trae y explica que es lo que esperas.

Comment: @A.Cedano la idea es tener una carga inical de datos limitada para no tener muchos datos y luego tener una escucha en tiempo real para añadir datos

Comment: ¿No será que estás mezclando dos cosas distintas debido en el fondo a algún planteamiento erróneo?

Comment: @A.Cedano no lo se , la idea es tener una sala de chat y cuando entras cargar los mensajes de la sala pero no todos para no hacer una carga excesiva , y a partir de que estes dentro añadir nuevos mensajes